# Rails adding method to Ruby class issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am under:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p194
Rails 3.0.9
```

I would like to use in my view method **percent_of** with Numeric data type.

For example, `<%= 10.persent_of(50) %>` it's equal `20%`.

to do that I have created `lib/numeric.rb` file that contains

```
class Numeric
  def percent_of(n)
    self.to_f / n.to_f * 100.0
  end
end
```

But I got an error:

```
undefined method `percent_of' for 10:Fixnum
```

I was trying to add definition `require 'Numeric'` but it didn't help me.

Help me plz.

Comment: You may want to put your file in `config/initializers` instead. That way you don't need to require it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `require 'numeric'` instead. You're requiring the file, not the class.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` in your `application.rb` file. You should extend Fixnum instead of Numeric:

```
class Fixnum
  def percent_of(n)
    self.to_f / n.to_f * 100.0
  end
end
```

Then require or include this in application_helper.rb so that it is available to all views:

`require 'numeric'` or `include Numeric`